# Creating array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm having a newbie problem in C++.
I have a struct `Edge` defined as following:

```
struct Edge {
    int position[4];
    int average;
};
```

Now I need to create a lot of these structs and I created a helper-method for that, that creates an array of these structs based on some parameters:

```
Edge* createEdges(int some_parameters){
    Edge *edges = new Edge[8];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++){
        Edge edge;
        edge.position[0] = 1; //fill the rest of the edge array in the same manner
        edge.average = 10;

        edges[i] = edge;
    }

    return edges;
}
```

However when I now call: `Edge *edges = createEdges(int some_parameters)` there is no sensible data in the Edge array (out of scope?).

I think I'm mixing up some things here but I would prefer if I can make this work without resorting to the `vector` datastructures. Is this the normal way of handling this or should I declare the edge array myself and pass it to the helper method to fill it up?

**Edit:**

First of all, I want to thank everyone for there comments/hints/tips/advice/... they have helped me to find the problem that I overlooked so easily.
After I seen the replies that the code should work, I tested the simplified code aswell (something I should have done in the 1st place) and surprisingly, it worked! So then I checked to see why my real code didn't work and the simplified version did.
My real code looked like this:

```
Edge* createEdges(int some_parameters){
     Edge* edges = new Edge[8];
     if(some_parameter != 0){
          //create the edges as in my 1st snippet
          return NULL; //doh, should return edges here !
     } else { 
          return NULL;
     }
}
```

The reason why I had not seen that I simply returned the wrong value (NULL) was because the debugger showed me some `0xf6f6f6` addressess with some negative values for `edge.position` (something I don't quite understand, it should've just show me `0x000000`, perhaps I was just imagining things).

All in all, this was an important lesson in why to never code after 3am, nothing good will come of it!

Comment: What you have here appears to be correct.

Comment: @ahenderson but when he does `edges[i] = edge` it copies the contents of the struct into the array. `edges` is an array of structs, not of pointers.

Comment: @ahenderson - yes, but each of the local objects gets copied into the target array.

Comment: Use `std::vector<Edge>`. If you're using pointers or `new` and you're inexperienced at C++, then it's probably wrong.

Comment: @ahenderson - but it's being copied to the allocated array, then returned by reference.

Comment: You don't need the local object; just assign values to the `Edge` objects in the array directly.

Comment: @PeteBecker - yes, that's what I would have done.  No need for the local and the copy.

Comment: Minor tweaks aside, as @Dan said, the code looks right. What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: i tried the code and it works fine

Comment: I have to concur with the others. This looks right. If there is a defect it isn't in this (aside from *not* using a std container =P)

Comment: @ahenderson: The assingment operator for `Edge` will perform a bitwise copy, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: @Gorpik Thanks, I just confirmed that. The code works just fine. Can OP show how he's testing the function?

Comment: What does "there is no sensible data in the Edge array" mean exactly? If you are using the automatically generated `Edge` constructor, it won't automatically initialize any of the primitive `int` attributes. So, if you forget to initialize any of those in that loop, they will in general contain arbitrary data.
So, do indeed define a reasonable constructor as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: @ahenderson Please do not delete your comments when somebody answers them. Otherwise, whoever tries to follow the comment thread will just see answers to inexistent questions.

Comment: @Gorpik I confirm it and deleted it before yours came up.

Comment: @ahenderson OK. This has also happened to me sometimes :)

Comment: The code is fine, I explain why you see no "sensible data" below

Comment: (I wish I could put an @everyone in here) i'll edit my question in a bit to clarify the question, the answer and reply to the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit modified version that creates edges in the function, and returns a vector containing all created edges.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Edge {
    int position[4];
    int average;
};

std::vector< Edge > createEdges(int some_parameters){
    std::vector< Edge > edges( 8 );

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++){
        const Edge edge{ { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 10 };

        edges[i] = edge;
    }

    return edges;
}


int main()
{
    auto e( createEdges(5));

    std::cout<<e[0].average<<std::endl;
}
```

There are few modifications :

1. Instead of allocating an array of edges, and returning pointer, I return vector
2. the way edge objects are created, and initialized (I think this is what is asked)

Answer (score 3):

It's C++ use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Edge> createEdges(int some_parameters){
    std::vector<Edge> edges;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++){
        Edge edge;
        edge.position[0] = 1;
        edge.average = 10;
        edges.push_back(edge);
    }

    return edges;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have here works fine. What I feel you are forgetting, is that when you call

```
Edge *edges = createEdges(int some_parameters)
```

that edges variable is a pointer to the first element in your list. If you were to then do:

```
edges[0]
```

or:

```
edges[1]
```

you would see that these are different values, and you need to now loop through to access the array. Just keep in mind that you do not go passed the end of your array during a loop. This is why most people say to use vectors, because you can use more of the safety features with an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to C++! The helper-method for creating instances of a class (a struct in C++ is a class where all the fields are public) is called a constructor.
Here is how I would create instances of the edge class, using a constructor.

```
class Edge {
public:
    int position[4];
    int average;
    Edge();
};

Edge::Edge() //constructor
{
    position[0] = 1;//fill the rest of the edge array in the same manner
    average = 10;
}

int main()
{
    Edge* myEdge = new Edge(); //constructor called
    Edge* myEdges[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        myEdges[i] = new Edge();
    }
    return 0;
}
```